# Arduino avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0080 0x3d != 0xb2

Tags: c++, arduino

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Плата:"Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10813 -build-path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_21602 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_842581 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\admin\Documents\Arduino\sketch_dec12a\sketch_dec12a.ino

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10813 -build-path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_21602 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_842581 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\admin\Documents\Arduino\sketch_dec12a\sketch_dec12a.ino

Using board 'nano' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr

Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr

Detecting libraries used...

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602\\sketch\\sketch_dec12a.ino.cpp" -o nul -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE

Generating function prototypes...

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602\\sketch\\sketch_dec12a.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp" -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

Компиляция скетча...

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602\\sketch\\sketch_dec12a.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602\\sketch\\sketch_dec12a.ino.cpp.o"

Compiling libraries...

Compiling core...

Using precompiled core: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_842581\core\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328old_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a

Linking everything together...

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602\\sketch\\sketch_dec12a.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602/..\\arduino_cache_842581\\core\\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328old_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a" "-LC:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602" -lm

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.eep"

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.hex"

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-size" -A "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.elf"

Скетч использует 444 байт (1%) памяти устройства. Всего доступно 30720 байт.

Глобальные переменные используют 9 байт (0%) динамической памяти, оставляя 2039 байт для локальных переменных. Максимум: 2048 байт.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM6 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.hex:i 



avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch



         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"



         Using Port                    : COM6

         Using Programmer              : arduino

         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600

         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P

         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us

         PAGEL                         : PD7

         BS2                           : PC2

         RESET disposition             : dedicated

         RETRY pulse                   : SCK

         serial program mode           : yes

         parallel program mode         : yes

         Timeout                       : 200

         StabDelay                     : 100

         CmdexeDelay                   : 25

         SyncLoops                     : 32

         ByteDelay                     : 0

         PollIndex                     : 3

         PollValue                     : 0x53

         Memory Detail                 :



                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled

           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack

           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------

           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff

           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff

           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00



         Programmer Type : Arduino

         Description     : Arduino

         Hardware Version: 2

         Firmware Version: 1.16

         Vtarget         : 0.0 V

         Varef           : 0.0 V

         Oscillator      : Off

         SCK period      : 0.1 us



avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s



avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)

avrdude: reading input file "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.hex"

avrdude: writing flash (444 bytes):



Writing | avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

############avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

###################################### | 100% 21.52s



avrdude: 444 bytes of flash written

avrdude: verifying flash memory against C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.hex:

avrdude: load data flash data from input file C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.hex:

avrdude: input file C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_21602/sketch_dec12a.ino.hex contains 444 bytes

avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.11s



Проблема загрузки в плату. Помощь по загрузке: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload .

avrdude: verifying ...

avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0080

         0x3d != 0xb2

avrdude: verification error; content mismatch



avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Answer (score 2):

Текст `avrdude: verification error` говорит, что в результате записи скетча в микроконтроллер и его последующего чтения обратно, результат чтения не совпал с тем, что мы пытались записать.

Данная ошибка может возникать по следующим причинам:

1. Плохой контакт. Например, из-за некачественного кабеля или расшатанного разъема.
2. Недостаточное питание. Некоторые ноутбуки этим грешат, выдавая по USB 4.5 вольта вместо 5.
3. Брак самого микроконтроллера. Но это маловероятно.

То, что выше по логу появлялась строка `avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding` говорит в пользу первых двух версий.